# Regular grammar such that it rejects keywords

Tags: regular-languages, programming-languages, regular-expressions

I want to write a regular grammar that follows the C language. I almost wrote the grammar, but was not able to resolve how to define a variable.

Def: A variable can be any combination of characters, but it should not be an existing keyword.

I tried writing something like this but not sure how to write it:

```
<Var> -> {a-z}+ (!b<Kew1>|<Kew2>|<Kew3>|<Kew4>)
```

Here `<Kew1>.. <Kew4>` are already defined keywords like `int`, `for`, `while`, `read`, ...

Comment: This is usually done in a lexical pass.

Answer (score 2):

Actual compilers cheat here, instead of doing a full per character grammar they instead do a per token grammar.

This means that there is a tokenizer which will preparse the character stream with a regular language parser and emit a stream of tokens. These tokens are then the whitespace, operators, keywords, identifiers, etc.. This has the guarantee that a Identifier token is never going to be a keyword.

```
<Var> -> Identifier
```

If you really want to have the per character grammar you will need to implement the DFA for parsing the keywords as a grammar:

```
<Var> -> (all letters that aren't the start of a keyword) {a-z}*
<Var> -> i ({a-mo-z} {a-z}*)?
<Var> -> in ({a-su-z} {a-z}*)?
<KeyWordINT> -> int
etc.
```